# wp_head function is displaying testing 123 and I do not know why?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[image: testing 123]

When I remove the wp_head function the testing 123 disappears.

I was doing something with my files where I was putting in testing 123 prior to this happening but, I wasn't working in the header.php folder.

I evem went to the folder where the wp_head function is located and I couldn't find the test 123.

Now, if I want to remove the testing 123 I got to start from scratch or remove the wp_head function to get the testing 123 to disappear.

If anybody has any ideas of where I should look to figure this out it be greatly appreciated.

crazy thing is all the file I have coded for this project none of them have testing123 inside of it. This strictly only happens when I add the wp_head function.

See above as I described what I tried above.

Comment: If there is no `testing123` in theme then most probably it is coming from the plugin. Please disable all plugins and check again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT! I had my single-about.php file inside my must use plugins folder. Idk, how in the world it got mixed in with my wp_head but, it's gone now.